# How to delete some roles in on_guild_remove(guild) function in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my discord.py bot delete some roles when a guild owner kicks my bot from the server.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    await dc.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted").delete()
```

However - I always get an error:

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

My bot application's role is at the highest place in the role hierarchy; all intents are enabled, but this is still happening. Could you please tell me why is this happening and show me a solution?

Comment: bot is no longer in the guild -> doesn't have all the permissions that had before -> cannot delete the role

Comment: So it's just impossible to do that action?

Comment: Sadly yes, it's not possible. A alternative would be to cleanup and delete the role in a command, then leave.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. Thanks anyway. Maybe you could add your answer so I could mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do anything once the bot has left the guild since it doesn't have the necessary permissions anymore, an alternative is to create a `leave` command and do all the cleanup there and then leave.